# MariaDB join error when using group by instead of distinct

Tags: mariadb

I found an error in my database. I reduced it to a simple test. I have two tables, A and B. Both have one column: ID. In A, I put every number from 1 to 100 as an ID. In B, I only put even numbers 2 trough 100, but I did not make it a unique column. I put every number in a random number of times. So, there are 100 rows in A (1 through 100) and 542 rows in B (repetition of values 2 through 100).

This query does not work:

```
select a.id from a join (select id from b group by id) x on a.id=x.id;
```

I get 100 rows with ID values 1 through 100. So, I am getting every row from A as though this is an outer join.

This query does work:

```
select a.id from a join (select distinct(id) id from b) x on a.id=x.id;
```

Now, I only get even IDs 2 through 100.

The only difference is the subquery. In one, I use group by to get distinct ID values. In the other, I use the distinct command. This tells me that group by isn't doing what I think it is doing. So, is this "normal" behavior for MariaDB or is my database messed up?

I am using a free tier MariaDB instance on AWS. So, I have very little access to settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, the easiest solution is to turn off `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` flag for your DB:

`mysql > SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));`

And probably worth reading a bit more about group mode in SQL.
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-mode/#only_full_group_by

Comment: That is exactly what happened, but the really weird thing is that it wasn't a problem until this month. So, AWS must have changed their settings.

Comment: I agree it's weird. Probably something has been upgraded.